# ¿Como hago para validar mi formulario en una ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, django

Quiero hacer la validación de mi formulario en una ventana modal? e intentado de varias formas me valida el formulario pero cuando le doy aceptar no me retorna a la ventana modal y la información se envía causándome un error de django, quiero saber si se puede validar campo por campo y que me retorne a la ventana modal con el error.

Este es mi formulario en la ventana modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="agregarboncheo" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="cerrarmodal" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
            <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Nuevo Boncheo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form class="formatolinea" method="post" name="nregistro">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label>Bonchador</label>
                    <select required="" name="boncheador">
                        <option>Nombre del bonchador</option>
                        {% for obj in bonchador %}
                        <option>{{obj.nombre}} {{obj.apellidos}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <label>Variedad</label>
                    <select required="" name="variedad">
                        <option>Seleccione la variedad</option>
                        <option>freedom</option>
                        <option>vendela</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Bonches</label>
                    <input type="number" name="bonches" placeholder="Cantidad de bonches">
                    <label>Unidades</label>
                    <select id="unidades" name="unidades" onChange="mostrarl(this.value);">
                        <option>Seleccione las unidades</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Grado</label>
                    <select required="" name="grado">
                        <option>Seleccione el grado</option>
                        <option>40</option>
                        <option>50</option>
                        <option>60</option>
                        <option>70</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Lámina</label>
                    <select required="" name="lamina">
                        <option>Seleccione la lamina</option>
                        <optgroup label="Lamina" id="lamina1" style='display: none;'>
                            <option>Benchmark</option>
                            <option>Golden</option>
                            <option>Microcorrugada</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Lamina" id="lamina2" style='display: none;'>
                            <option>Pet Transparante con papel</option>
                            <option>Transparante</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                    <button class="guardar" type="submit" onclick="mensajes();"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                    <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.containerfluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modalbody -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
        <!-- /.modalfooter -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: La validación de los datos que envias al formulario se hace por lo general en la vista que procesa el formulario. Es decr, __la validación se hace en Django__. Si quieres validar en el lado del cliente, puedes usar alguna librería o framework de JavaScript. Por otro lado, el error que obtienes es porque las _«ventanas modales»_ no son páginas, son adornos hechos con CSS y JavaScript, por lo que debes usar esas técnicas para mostrar los datos que quieres.

Comment: Es por eso quiero saber como hago con JavaScript para validar el formulario y si algo esta mal me retorne al modal antes de enviar la información pero no se como hacerlo @toledano

Comment: Busca en Google [_«Validar formularios con javascript»_](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=validar+formularios+javascript) y selecciona alguna de las soliciones que encuentres. Si se te presenta algún problema, recuerda seguir [estas directrices](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) al hacer tu pregunta. Recuerda que el ejemplo es __sobre lo que estás haciendo para resolver tu problema__.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho y me validad la información lo que no he podido hacer es que me retorne a la ventana modal donde tengo la información.

Comment: Django te regresa __a la página__ que le indiques. Si quieres que tu página muestre un dialogo modal, debes poco que ver con Django y mas con el framework que uses en el frontend. Es decir, los datos del formulario ya van en el _request_, lo que tu quieres es __abrir un modal usando una URL__, pero de nuevo, __eso no tiene que ver con Django__.

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer pero gracias por tu ayuda :D

Comment: Que bien. Te invito a que tu misma respondas a esta pregunta, de esta manera queda un registro que puede ayudar a otros usuarios en tu misma situación. Además de que ganas reputaciión en el sitio, medallas, reconocimiento y privilegios.